# How to make member template functinon a friend in VC7

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2003

I'm trying to make a member template function, declared in a non-template base class, a friend of the derived class.  Both methods of declaring it work using Visual Studio 2012.  However, Visual Studio 2003 complains with errors below.  As a workaround I'm declaring the base class as a friend, but I'd like to avoid that.
Is this a limitation of VS2003 or is there another way?

```
template<class T> friend CBase* CBase::Make() const;
```

and

```
friend CBase* CBase::Make<CChild>() const;
```

Context:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

class CBase
{
public:
  virtual CBase* MakeSameObj() = 0;
  const std::string& Get() const { return data; }

  CBase() { data += __FUNCSIG__; }

protected:
  template<class T>
    CBase* Make() const
  {
    CBase* pt = new T(__FUNCSIG__);
    return pt;
  }

  std::string data;
};

class CChild
  : public CBase
{
public:
  CChild() : CBase() { data += " "; data += __FUNCSIG__; }
private:
  CChild(char* param) : CBase() { data += " "; data += param; }
  CBase* MakeSameObj() { return Make<CChild>(); }

  //error C2245: non-existent member function 'Make' specified as friend (member function signature does not match any overload)
  template<class T> friend CBase* CBase::Make() const;

  //error C2768: 'CBase::Make' : illegal use of explicit template arguments
  friend CBase* CBase::Make<CChild>() const;
  //Ok
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  CBase* pt  = new CChild;
  CBase* pt1 = pt->MakeSameObj();

  std::cout << pt->Get().c_str() << std::endl;
  std::cout << pt1->Get().c_str() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```